# Finding the probability mass function of the random variable $X$ that counts the number of married couples in a selection of four people

Tags: probability

There are $10$ married couples in a room. You are going to randomly select $4$ people from this group. Find the probability mass function of the random variable $X$ that counts the number of married couples in your selection. Find $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$?

I started this by using the Bernoulli formula which is: 
$$P(X=x) = \binom{10}{x}(.5)^x(1-.5)^{10-x}$$

I was wondering if I am doing this correctly.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Notice that there will either be no married couples, one married couple, or two married couples.  If there are no married couples, then you have to select one person each from four of the ten couples.  If there is one married couple, then you have to select the couple and one person each from two of the other nine couples.  If there are two married couples, you have to select two of the ten couples.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, there are $n$ married couples in a room, and you select $2k$ people from them. Suppose $M(n, k)$ is the number of married couples among them.

We know, that $P(M(n, k) \in \{0, 1, ..., k\})=1$. Also, $P(M(n, k)=0)=\frac{2^{2k}C_n^{2k}}{C_{2n}^{2k}}$, as to select no married couples we have to select $2k$ representatives from $2k$ married couples.

If $M(n, k) > 1$ we can remove one of the married couples among those that were selected from the initial "pool" and thus get that $P(M(n, k) = t) = \frac{k(2k - 1)}{n(2n-1)}P(M(n-1, k-1)= t-1)$.

This is sufficient to form a recurrence.